# I have to an int value from a Moneybag

Tags: java, variables, object

I have to subtract a specific amount from an object variable mb2. At first I have to subtract 500, which is over the amount in the MoneyBag. My question is how to make the header of the subtract method.Right now I have this code which I cannot Change:

```
   mb2 = mb2.subtract(500);
```

I tried to do it by using this as a method header and my code along with it.

```
    public MoneyBag subtract(int p){
      int v = this.Value//which is an int
      if(v<p){
         System.out.println("Insufficient Funds");
      }
      else{
      }
    }
```

I do not know what to return since it is a MoneyBag I am comparing. I can get it to compile, but the value of mb2 which is 182, automatically drops to zero after my first if statement. I don't really need to return anything. I need to put variable for add into another method, but I already know how to do that.

Comment: You have a bracket facing the wrong way. Not sure if that is an issue with your code or your copypasta.

Comment: @rene Its not the bracket i just entered that incorrectly